# How to add more allowed values to the Headers of Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, security

I am aware that GeoServer comes with the feature of '[Configuring HTTP Header Proxy Authentication](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/tutorials/httpheaderproxy/index.html)'. However, I only understand how to customize the 'Header attribute', but the not the 'Header value'.

For example, the "sdf09rt2s: admin":

- **Header attribute** is 'sdf09rt2s'
- **Header value** is 'admin'

How can I create more **Header value**? (such as: 'user1', 'user2', etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. It involves few steps:

1. Add a new role (eg: testRole)
2. Add a new user under 'Users,Groups,Roles' tab (eg: testUser)
3. Assign the new role to the new user
4. Add a new rule under the Service access rules list.

**The access right is based on Role**. So, if you want a user to be able to access it, it is required to Assign the role to that user (which i forgot before i post the question).